# Cannot enable debug mode in production server in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to enable debug mode in browser as follows:

```
from werkzeug.debug import DebuggedApplication  

application = Flask(__name__)
app = application
application = DebuggedApplication(app, True)
```

But it does not enable debug mode in my production server Apache under `mod_wsgi`.

Did I have something wrong? Also the `export` method doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DebuggedApplication()` middleware only works if an uncaught exception reaches it.
Flask, in production mode, catches all exceptions so these never reach the middleware.

You need to explicitly tell Flask to not catch all exceptions with:

```
PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True
```

in your configuration. From the [relevant documenation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/config/#PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS):

> #### `PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS`
>
> Exceptions are re-raised rather than being handled by the app’s error handlers. If not set, this is implicitly true if `TESTING` or `DEBUG` is enabled.

You can set it on the `app` object before wrapping it in the `DebuggedApplication` middleware:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS'] = True
app.wsgi_app = DebuggedApplication(app.wsgi_app, True)
```

Note that this *only* tells Flask to not catch all exceptions any more. You may also want to set other configuration options such as [`PRESERVE_CONTEXT_ON_EXCEPTION`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/config/#PRESERVE_CONTEXT_ON_EXCEPTION), or you could just enable debug mode with `app.debug = True`.

Comment: This wordked like a charm thanks! What about `app.debug = True` where should i place this and how in order to work?

Comment: @ΝικόλαοςΒέργος: in the same location, instead of `app.config['PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS'] = True`. Take into account that setting debug mode on means that template reloading is enabled and some other debug settings on exception handling.

Comment: And what exactly are their difference? Also you seem to know very well and i want to ask you if you can help me with this question too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52593499/form-a-url-link-with-utf-8-encoding

Comment: @ΝικόλαοςΒέργος: `PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS` is automatically enabled when `app.debug` is set, but there are more such settings. Setting `app.debug = True` enables all those settings in one go.